# Why does this simple numpy multiply operation raise an "invalid number of arguments" error?

Tags: python, numpy

This works

```
numpy.multiply(13, 3)
```

This doesn't

```
numpy.multiply(x1=13, x2=3)
```

It raises an `invalid number of arguments` exception. Can someone explain why please. I tried to follow the documentation but got a bit lost with the `/`, and `*` characters which are included in the argument list. If you could explain the meaning of these too it would be appreciated.

Comment: Arguments before the slash are positional only, so you cannot pass them as keyword arguments; read the help(range) question for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html

The `/` and `*` delimit *positional-only* and *keyword-only* arguments, respectively. Any arguments listed *before* the `/` can only be given as positional arguments, with no keyword (i.e. no `x1`, `x2`). Arguments listed *after* the `*` can only be given *with* a keyword.

[Keyword-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/#specification)

[Positional-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/#syntax-and-semantics)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help